# Mindbody api (using python) emitting not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: python, xml, suds, mindbody

Hi friends I am trying to implement Mindbody API using python. But I am getting error that caused my work down. Down the page error is shown.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Appointment.py", line 6, in <module>
    class AppointmentService():
  File "Appointment.py", line 10, in AppointmentService
    service = Client(urlService)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 112, in __init__
    self.wsdl = reader.open(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\reader.py", line 152, in open
    d = self.fn(url, self.options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\wsdl.py", line 136, in __init__
    d = reader.open(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\reader.py", line 79, in open
    d = self.download(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\reader.py", line 101, in download
    return sax.parse(string=content)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\suds\sax\parser.py", line 136, in parse
    sax.parse(source)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 110, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 217, in feed
    self._err_handler.fatalError(exc)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\handler.py", line 38, in fatalError
    raise exception
xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException: <unknown>:9:673: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDU0g.jpg)

actually I am unable to resolve this problem and don't know the reason behind the error

Comment: You probably should provide that piece of your code that produced this error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are implementing third party API so you should take care of input which are sent to the server. Mainly this type of error occurs due to improper formatting of input and server was not able to understand your request. So please check you are hitting right service call with required parameter as in the format. Do refer to [MindBody Api documentation](https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/Documentation/GettingStarted)

Good example and explanation can be found here for MindBody pyton integration http://www.mindbodydeveloper.com/mindbody-integration-python-example/